# How do I install expo-cli@3.11.3 on mac

Tags: node.js, expo

ERROR: Node.js version 8.14.0 is no longer supported.

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:

- > =10.13.0 <11.0.0 (Active LTS)
- > =12.0.0 <13.0.0 (Active LTS)
- > =13.0.0 <14.0.0 (Current Release)

Comment: You have to update your NodeJS (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using older versions of node.js, Its hardly impossible to install expo-cli with < node V10. So the trick here is update your node version to a stable one and roll back to the older version that supports your application.